# how to turn off eslint rule `angular/file-name` in eslint-plugin-angular

Tags: angularjs, webpack, eslint

i have configuration like this.

`module.exports = {
    "globals": {
        "angular": 1
    },
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    extends: ['plugin:angular/johnpapa', 'eslint:recommended'],

```
"parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module"
},
"plugins": [
    "angular"
],
"rules": {
    "no-console": 0,
    "angular/ng_controller_name": 0,
    "indent": [
        "error",
        "tab"
    ],
    "linebreak-style": [
        "error",
        "unix"
    ],
    "quotes": [
        "error",
        "single"
    ],
    "semi": [
        "error",
        "always"
    ]
}
```

};
`

and i get this warning in terminal

`Filename must be "callsController.js" angular/file-name`

Comment: there isn't enough information here to understand what your problem is at all.

Comment: however, it *seems like* you are asking about filename rules being implemented by a custom plugin;  I would probably start with that plugin's documentation:  https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular/blob/master/docs/file-name.md

Answer (score 4):

The angular plugin is running a file name rule, I'm guessing by default since I don't see it in your rule list. You should be able to override this with `"angular/file-name":0` in your eslintrc.

Answer (score 3):

In your `.eslintrc` add `"angular/file-name": 0` in the **rules** section, like so:

```
{
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "plugins": ["angular"],
    "env": {
        ...
    },
    "globals": {
        "angular": true,
        "module": true,
        "inject": true
    },
    "rules": {
        "angular/file-name": 0
    }
}
```